# How to pass and use arguments in ./configure?

Tags: assert, configure

I would like to be able pass arguments to `./configure` script, so it would add NDEBUG used by  to my generated header file. How can I do that? My `configure` script is generated from `configure.ac`.

I already one great answer, but it seems that I my question is wrong. The option would have to remove this `NDEBUG`, because by default I would like to have assertions turned off. There is no AC_UNDEFINE, so I need to use some trick: define `ASSERT_ON`, which would turn off `NDEBUG`. Is there any easier, better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the AC_ARG_ENABLE() macro in your configure.ac file to trigger an action when someone adds --enable-foo to your command line options.

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(foo, "used to turn on the NDEBUG flag",
  [ AC_DEFINE(NDEBUG) ]
)
```

Comment: That is great answer and I would gladly accept, but please take a look at my edit. Maybe you could also help me with this?

Comment: If you want to unset a previously set variable within autoconf, you should be able to turn off the variable name itself.  Maybe.  See the config.cache file for the list of variable names that you might be able to turn off with a simple varname="" type setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AH_VERBATIM` in order to add extra data to your `config.h.in` (and thus, `config.h` file).

The thing is, `autoconf` is going to comment out anything that looks like a `#undef` statement when producing the `config.h` file out of the template.

There is a preprocessor trick to avoid that: use `#/**/undef/**/`. The C preprocessor is going to strip the comments first, but autoconf will not see that as a `#undef` statement.

To recap, in order to enforce `NDEBUG` being undefined:

```
AH_VERBATIM([NDEBUG], [/* Never ever ignore assertions */
#ifdef NDEBUG
#/**/undef/**/ NDEBUG
#endif])
```